# multiple Insert values in a loop

Tags: plsql

I thought I was able to do this kind of thing:

```
BEGIN
    FOR r_var IN (select var1 from schema.table1 where var2 = 2)
    LOOP
        insert into schema.table2(col1,col2,col3,col4) 
        select r_var.var1, count(*), 'aString', 0
        from schema.table2 
        where col1 = r_var.var1 group by r_var.var1;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

The issue is a "unique constraint violated".
I think the issue comes when I use a select on the same table than the one I use for the inser into.
How can I fix this?

Thx!

EDIT: table2 got a check is not null constraint on col1 and col2, and two foreign keys targetting table1 and another table not used there.

EDIT2: I still not reach a solution, so I split my problem.
First I checked if I was able to get the count correctly with this query:

```
SET SERVER OUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    count_rows NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR r_var IN (select var1 from schema.table1 where var2 = 2) 
    LOOP
        select count(*) into count_rows from schema.table2 where col1 = r_var .var1;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('order for var1 : ' || r_var.col1 || ' is ' || count_rows + 1);
    END LOOP;
 END;
```

result:

```
order for var1: 144 is 20
order for var1: 3000 is 10
order for var1: 3001 is 9
order for var1: 3003 is 3
order for var1: 110 is 10
order for var1: 114 is 12
order for var1: 115 is 81
order for var1: 116 is 11
order for var1: 123 is 10
```

I then tried to insert just one row in the table:

```
insert into schema.table2(col1, col2, col3, col4) values(144, 20, 'aString', 0);
```

Which works without issue !

But still, when I run the loop below, I got a 'unique constraint violated' issue:

```
DECLARE
count_rows NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR r_var IN (select var1 from schema.table1 where var2 = 2) 
    LOOP
        select count(*) into count_rows from schema.table2 where col1 = r_var.var1;
        insert into schema.table2(col1, col2, col3, col4) values(r_var.var1, count_rows + 1, 'aString', 0);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: What unique constraint(s) does `table2` have?

Comment: The code is valid apart from a missing `group by r_var.var1`. You probably need a `not exists` clause or `minus` subquery to avoid the duplication, or change it to a `merge`.

Comment: You do not need a unique constraint to ensure "those columns are not null". You  need a [NOT NULL constraint](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-not-null/). There may indeed be other reasons to have a unique constraint on one or both of then but not for the reason stated. A unique constraint tells the DBMS that a value in the column is allowed to only exist one time no how many rows exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was from the insert which was trying to insert a row with col1 and col2 of an already similar existing row. A constraint were preventing a row to be inserted when an already existing row with the same col1 and col2 was present.
The query was not doing exactly what I wanted, replacing count(*) by max(col2) solved the issue:

```
DECLARE
    max_rows NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR r_var IN (select var1 from schema.table1 where var2 = 2) 
    LOOP
        select max(col2) into max_rows from schema.table2 where col1 = r_var.var1;
        insert into schema.table2(col1, col2, col3, col4) values(r_var.var1, max_rows + 1, 'aString', 0);
    END LOOP;
END;
```